# PDO exception on correct MySql query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to update a MySql database using PDO in PHP.
I need to launch 4 lines of SQL code. The last one is the SELECT statement, which should return only one integer value.

The error thrown is:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\set-lesson-finished.php:22
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php\set-lesson-finished.php(22): PDOStatement->fetchColumn()
#1 {main}
```

And here is the code:

```
try {
$db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS, array(
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$query_save = $db_connection->prepare('
DELETE FROM unfinished_lessons WHERE bought_id = :bought_id;
INSERT INTO finished_lessons VALUES (:bought_id, :time_invested, NOW());
UPDATE users SET points = points + :points_earned WHERE id = :user_id;
SELECT points FROM users WHERE id = :user_id;
');
$query_save->bindValue(':user_id', (int)$_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query_save->bindValue(':bought_id', (int)$_POST['bought_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query_save->bindValue(':time_invested', (int)$_POST['time_invested'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query_save->bindValue(':points_earned', (int)$_POST['points_earned'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query_save->execute();
echo $query_save->fetchColumn();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo $e;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to bind `:user_id` twice, that's going to cause an issue. (*Same with `:bought_id`..?*)

Comment: user_id and bought_id are bound once, but each of them is used twice. Anyway, I've tried to comment out second and third statements, so each variable is used once, but the code still throws the same exception.

Comment: Try running the queries separately, because you can't `fetchColumn()` after an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: What is your php version? Php 5.3+ have support for multiple queries and are you using mysqlnd ? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php

Comment: I'm using 5.4. It might be mysqlnd, because it's default in 5.4

Comment: Why are there two tables for lessons instead of a single table with a flag field? You don't even need a new field for that, time_invested<>0 would probably do.

Comment: unfinished_lessons table has different fields from those of finished_lessons, because it stores information about what is done and what is not yet done by the user, while finished_lessons does care only about when the lesson was finished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a single query but four queries together. You'll get four different result sets which need to be retrieved independently.

The error you're seeing is occurring because you can't call `fetchColumn()` on a `DELETE` query (it doesn't return a result set). Likewise for `INSERT` and `UPDATE`.

You could experiment with [PDOStatement::nextRowSet()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php), but it's probably easier to run the four queries separately. If you're concerned about having an all-or-nothing update you should use a transaction with `PDO::beginTransaction()` and `PDO::commit()`

Comment: Transactions are the correct way to handle this, because it allows rolling back if anything fails. Instead of leaving behind "stranded" data if some statement along the way fails.

Comment: Definitely transactions are the way to go with this. +1 for in-depth answer.

Answer (score 3):

When queries gets complex you need to use a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE your_sp(IN `p_bought_id`, IN `p_time_invested`, IN `p_points_earned`, IN `p_user_id`)
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM unfinished_lessons WHERE bought_id = p_bought_id;
        INSERT INTO finished_lessons VALUES (p_bought_id, p_time_invested, NOW());
        UPDATE users SET points = points + p_points_earned WHERE id = p_user_id;
        SELECT points FROM users WHERE id = p_user_id;
    END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

You call it in one query like this:

```
$query_save = $db_connection->prepare('
call your_sp(:bought_id, :time_invested,:points_earned, :user_id)
');
```

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, but decided not to go this route. I've read that procedures don't make a performance difference and I know that they are a bit harder to maintain than PHP code. I can transfer all my PHP to a new hosting server but may forget to add stored procedures.

Comment: actually they perform better if you execute them multiple times because of caching, it also has a maintenance advantage because you can change your db logic without ever touching the PHP code. But you do have a valid point!

Comment: Maybe I'll execute some tests when my app will be on optimization stage.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **mysqli** extension (and **not PDO**) if you **absolutely want to** run multiple statements at the same time. 
As you can see in this [Feature comparison](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqlinfo.api.choosing.html) (see the comparison table), only *ext/mysqli* has full support for multiple MySQL queries (and also supports all MySQL 5.1+ functionnality). 
And, as Drupal's dawehner says, [MySQL PDO no longer allows multiple database queries to be executed at the same time](https://www.drupal.org/node/2463973).

Answer (score 0):

I've split the queries in four and everything works as expected:

```
$db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS, array(
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$db_connection->beginTransaction();
$query = $db_connection->prepare('DELETE FROM planz_unfinished_lessons WHERE bought_id = :bought_id;');
$query->bindValue(':bought_id', (int)$_POST['bought_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$query = $db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO planz_finished_lessons VALUES (:bought_id, :time_invested, NOW())');
$query->bindValue(':bought_id', (int)$_POST['bought_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue(':time_invested', (int)$_POST['time_invested'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$query = $db_connection->prepare('UPDATE planz_users SET points = points + :points_earned WHERE id = :user_id');
$query->bindValue(':points_earned', (int)$_POST['points_earned'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue(':user_id', (int)$_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$query_check = $db_connection->prepare('SELECT points FROM planz_users WHERE id = :user_id');
$query_check->bindValue(':user_id', (int)$_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query_check->execute();
$db_connection->commit();
$_SESSION['points'] = $query_check->fetchColumn();
echo $_SESSION['points'];
```

Note the use of `beginTransaction` and `commit`, as they should speed up the querying.